# Error Cancelling Contribution - The Contribution Could not be Cancelled

Tags: civimember, paypal

CiviCRM 4.7.17 on Drupal 7, using Paypal Payment Pro processor. When clicking on a membership and canceling automatic renewal/payments, it gives the error

> Error Cancelling Contribution - The Contribution Could not be Cancelled

If we keep "Notify Paypal Pro" selected on the following screen we receive the error, if we de-select it the error does not occur, and the recurring contribution is cancelled.

How could we begin to debug this? Is there special set up required to have CiviCRM able to manage our Paypal recurring payment profiles?

Comment: Hi. did you ever get to the bottom of this one?

Comment: We didn't, and we're likely moving to the iATS payment processor and seeing if that works.

Comment: FYI I think the fix may be here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20800